# Define a Typescript type for a function with none or many different parameter types

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have a function which binds a passed function to a HTMLElement:

```
  global.d.ts:
  type tPrimitivRestParams = (number | object | string)[];
  type tDefaultVoidFunction = (...params: tPrimitivRestParams) => void;
```

```
  export default class AwesomeFunctions {
    public static addClickCallback(id: HTMLElement, func: tDefaultVoidFunction, scope: object, ...argArray: tPrimitivRestParams): void {
      [...] // checks
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-null/no-null
      element.onclick = func ? func.bind(scope, ...argArray) : null;
    }
  }
```

```
  export default class AwesomeClass {
    private bindMe(id: string):void {}
    private bindMeToo():void {}
    private bindMeThree(a:string, b: number, c: object): void {}
    private bindMeFour(clazz: SomeClass): void {}

    private binder():void {
      AwesomeFunctions.addClickCallback(document.getElementById('...'), this.bindMeToo, this); // TS says yes
      AwesomeFunctions.addClickCallback(document.getElementById('...'), this.bindMe, this, 'param'); // TS says no
      AwesomeFunctions.addClickCallback(document.getElementById('...'), this.bindMeThree, this, 'param', 2, {whoopi: 'goldberg', age: 24, 'actual-age': 'dontcha dare askn!!!'}); // TS says no
      AwesomeFunctions.addClickCallback(document.getElementById('...'), this.bindMeThree, this, new SomeClass()); // TS says no
    }
  }
```

It's working fine with JS but TS yells for all but the first:

```
// Example for bindMe
S2345: Argument of type '(id: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'tDefaultVoidFunction'.
```

If I do this:

```
AwesomeFunctions.addClickCallback(..., this.bindMe as tDefaultVoidFunction , ...);
```

TS is satisfied, but it seems wrong to me.

I know it's a problem with the tDefaultVoidFunction type. Is it possible to define a type to make TS happy with all the bindings? I can't use any, null or Function.

###### Sidequestion:

I also could do this:

```
AwesomeFunctions.addClickCallback(..., () => this.bindMe('param'), this);
```

TS is also satisfied but 95% of the addClickCallback function gets pointless. But that's not the reason for my hesitation of using an arrow function. I fear the scopes could differ. As far as I can tell, the scope is always a this. So in this case I claim the arrow function and the bind act the same. Am I wrong?

---

**Reproducible example:**

```js
type tPrimitivRestParams = (number | object | string)[];
type tDefaultVoidFunction = (...params: tPrimitivRestParams) => void;

class AwesomeFunctions {
    public static addClickCallback(id: string, func: tDefaultVoidFunction, scope: object, ...argArray: tPrimitivRestParams): void {
        // DO something
    }
}

class AwesomeClass {
    private bindMe(id: string):void {}
    private bindMeToo():void {}
    private bindMeThree(a:string, b: number, c: object): void {}

    private binder():void {
        AwesomeFunctions.addClickCallback('A', this.bindMeToo, this);
        AwesomeFunctions.addClickCallback('B', this.bindMe, this, 'param');
        AwesomeFunctions.addClickCallback('C', this.bindMeThree, this, 'param', 2, {whoopi: 'goldberg', age: 24, 'actual-age': 'dontcha dare askn!!!'});
    }
}
```

Playground: [TS Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMAKBOBLAto4iBuAlCBnOAhvAcrlALxQAUAdgK7IBGE8UAPlAPaMBWEAxsHZR8SGgHMAlAG0AugG4AUKEgwAIhABmBOgBtgANU6IAJgDE6NQYk40K1AHROwRErgBcMBCjSYc%20WFdSSQoAPigMYxMlRX5dAlwyAEEAdzxOZAgLK3RbMgBvRShiqDA6Rl1EfhFgAnRqghMTAGFK-gBrZoJdXUYCDqpTT1FECQAaKE1Lfk9gDW09Qyjs61sJ3H5OSE9uPkEJpwcicST4YhBZ71R0bDxCYmDPSNMoQpL3qAB6T6g1AHkRBkIMAABajcRFEoAX0UMNi8USUAAcpxgABlTipdKZVoJAqKWEEuJ4qBY3BA3GIt4lMBIDB1aCMUYmACyEEGJmGwDEUnczxMrxh71pmAZUCZNFZEAAKpxOFRJHyooLIcURfTgIzmWzpSD4BB2QR3CNxuLPPQmCwJjMuLwBMBFRFlfk4cK6WKJSYWAqlS9qR9SWlyZkVrkaLgjk1WlVOt1ev12lQAORJJMTUGICOenVy9Ng3CSJQB4pkoGhmzhyMtNqxnp9AZJgBCaZg%20Yc2YgeczEyTLgeScLqo%20pZD0zDEca1ZjXTrCeTzRbGaz2pleoNXdwPb7JBbACYJvkUiC5WBEJ4k%20JOLoTMx4OIWwRxBBPLuACw9-rAOjdAC0j4gSbniYtjAPwIIEFAJhENACTtDQACEiFJlCg7vDCUJAA)

Comment: please provide reproducibe example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what you tell the compiler:

```
type tDefaultVoidFunction = (...params: (number | object | string)[]) => void;
```

The callback must accept any number of parameters where each parameter must accept number | object | string.

Let's have a look at your function...

```
const example: tDefaultVoidFunction = (id: string): void {}
```

The parameter accepts only strings and so the compiler will tell you that's wrong. (number and object missing)

You can define multiple allowed signatures by using union types:

```
type tDefaultVoidFunction = ((id: string) => void) 
    | (() => void) 
    | ((a: string, b: number, c: object) => void) 
    | ((clazz: SomeClass) => void);
```

Notes:

- `private function bindMe(id: string):void {}` is no valid TypeScript code inside of classes, I guess it's just a typo.
- Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html

### Update based on comments

Possible option:

Instead of writing:

```
AwesomeFunctions.addClickCallback(document.getElementById('...'), this.bindMeToo, this);
```

use:

```
document.getElementById('...')?.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.bindMeTo());
// ignoring that we do not provide valid parameters in both cases
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the typo. Alot of switching between PHP and TS. ;) But I obiously explained my question not enough. I know the reason why TS complains. But I cannot tell TS every Class I might want to pass. That would be ridiculous. I have 40+ classes. The functions could also take only a number, or only a string, or only an array. You can't tell me I have to tell TS every possible type. I would loose my faith. In objects we have something like {[key: string]: ...} I hope something is possible with functions too.

Comment: If you want to accept every function the answer is `Function` which is often blocked because it can't be reliable. When you call your callback, you pass parameters and the available parameters define the allowed signature. How would you ensure the your callback is always called with the right parameters? In your code, you bind to `onclick` which will pass the event as parameter. How should this work with a function that expects a string? It will not get the string but a `PointerEvent` and so it will fail.

Comment: Sounds logically. But then I would rather use a wrapper function like I did in my sidequestion example. It is just a function with no params calling the function with parameters I wanted to bind. Problem is, I will have to brief a few devs and I hoped I could avoid that. Or still can. Maybe there is still another solution.

Comment: Classes and arrow functions bring JavaScript more to a "PHP/C#/Java-like" style for handling `this`. E.g. "Arrow functions establish "this" based on the scope the Arrow function is defined within." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - there may be no reason to `bind()` in this world. E.g. (inside class method) `el.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.anotherClassMethod())` could be an option.

Comment: The wrapper function is currently the favored at work. And there are only 100+ LOCs we have to change. :) Test cases run without complains for now. I still have to figure out, if the type tDefaultVoidFunction is obsolete now. Anyway... Thanks for your help. I will accept the answer the day we are finished changing our code. Would be end of this week aprox.